# Unable to navigate to User Defined Keyword, when it is called from Robot Template

Tags: python, testing, automation, robotframework, robotframework-ide

1. I am using Robot Test templates for writing tests.(http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-templates)
2. The template has a user defined keyword. In my case, I have something like "Search for Specific Kingdom" and that keyword is defined in the same suite.

My expectation is that, if I press CNTRL+click on that, it should take me to the keyword.
But actually it doesn't.

Please note that, I have another such template defined in some other test case in the same suite. Navigation to keyword works like a champ there, if I CNTRL+click.

What could be the problem in the first case?
The keyword has python method calls.
I have RIDE 1.5.2.1 running on Python 2.7.2.

Comment: Please tell us what Operative System you are using, and confirm the wxPython version too. Thanks.

Comment: OS is windows7. wxPython version is 2.8.12.1

Comment: Do you use an IDE? What is it?

Comment: Yes, I use RIDE

Comment: I still face issues, any help is much appreciated!